# This code is writing only one row in DB?

Tags: python, sqlite

This code is writing only one row in DB

I find no error in this code . . .

But why is this not inserting more than the first row ?

```
def transremovechars():
    cur.execute('drop table transforms')
    char_cfg = config.get('Transform_Variables', 'Chars_to_be_removed')      #Reads all the special chars to be removed from specialchars.txt#
    cur.execute('select * from originallist')
    for row in cur:                                                         #Applies transformation to remove chars for each row in a loop#
        company = row[0]
        for specialchars in char_cfg:
            company =  company.replace(specialchars, '')
        cur.execute('Insert into transforms (Transresult1) values (\'' + company + '\')')
    con.commit()
```

Comment: You should add `results = cur.fetchall()` and loop over `results` and not the cursor.

Comment: glglgl: Ok. That's just how I always have done it. So I supposed that was the way to go. But ok, then I know now, you can loop over the cursor.

Comment: glglgl: You removed your comment? Can or can't you iterate directly over the cursor?

Comment: @NiclasNilsson I am not sure; I only know it from MySQL and thought it was standard. Then I saw that it was about sqlite, which I don't know.

Comment: @NiclasNilsson According to [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), the cursor's support for iteration protocol is optional. But I have tested it now; the `sqlite3` module supports it.

Comment: This output is putting single row multiple times !

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `cur.fetchall()`:

```
def transremovechars():
    cur.execute('drop table transforms')
    char_cfg = config.get('Transform_Variables', 'Chars_to_be_removed')      #Reads all the special chars to be removed from specialchars.txt#
    cur.execute('select * from originallist')
    for row in cur.fetchall():                                                         #Applies transformation to remove chars for each row in a loop#
        company = row[0]
        for specialchars in char_cfg:
            company =  company.replace(specialchars, '')
        cur.execute('Insert into transforms (Transresult1) values (\'' + company + '\')')
    con.commit()
```

Comment: The cur.fetchall() is printing every row ! 6 times

Comment: by 'printing' you mean 'inserting a row into transforms table'?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to drop your table `transforms` before working with it. Are you sure you want that? Or maybe have you forgotten to show the code which creates it again?

Your `select *` might e overkill if you only use the 1st column. Maybe you want to name that field in the `SELECT`.

Besides, you should replace your INSERT line with

```
cur.execute('Insert into transforms (Transresult1) values (?)', company)
```

Iterating over the cursor should be fine, however. Maybe you could insert some `print` statements into your `for` loop...

Answer (score 1):

Comments to the effect that you should `cur.fetchall()` and iterate over that will work and be OK.  The real fault in your code is that once you use `cur` to insert, it is a "new thing" and the original generator is reset (cur has the `next()`) method.

You can use cur without doing fetchall as you wanted, just create a second cursor `ins_cur = con.curson()` and use both.  Many more *advanced* effects can be accomplished by iterating or using multiple cursors open on one connection.

And yes please use the correct [variable binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python) for your dbapi module.